# Zip a file in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, zip

I'm trying to zip a file from google collab and then download it.
The original file is too large and takes forever to download normally.
I'm having issues zipping it first.

```
!zip -r '/content/folder/filename.zip'.
```

`from google.colab import files files.download("filename")`

Answer (score 14):

```
!zip -r '/content/folder/"NewFileName.zip"' '/content/folder/"OrginalFileName"'
```

Comment: how do you add format to the file name in command line? !zip -r '/content/folder/"NewFileName"+"{0:03d}".format(i) +'.zip"' '/content/folder/"OrginalFileName"' wouldn't work due to the bracket

Answer (score 3):

That's how it worked for me

```
!zip -r /content/your_data.zip /content/your_data.your_file_extension
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
!zip '/content/folder/filename.zip'
```

to zip files.

Comment: This doesn't work, it results in zip error: Nothing to do!